# assign unique id to radio button on selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to assign unique id to radio button on select. I am not sure this is right way. I tried like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="radioExample">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.startDate = {
        id: new Date()
      };
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "value": new Date().getMilliseconds()
      };

      $scope.uniqueId = new Date().getMilliseconds();

    }]);
    </script>
    <form ng-controller="ExampleController" name="myForm">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{::uniqueId}}"  />

    Jan
  </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{::uniqueId}}" />

    Feb
  </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{::uniqueId}}" />

    Mar
  </label>
      <br />
      <tt>ID = {{uniqueId | json}}</tt>
      <br />
    </form>

 Note that `ng-value="specialValue"` sets radio item's value to be the value of `$scope.specialValue`.


  </body>

</html>
```

This prints the same value for all the radio buttons even after adding timestamp in milliseconds

Comment: Do you really need different `input radio`. Can you use `ng-repeat` and basically assign the id using `ng-change` based on what radio is selected?

Comment: @Dev-One my view is already defined. I need to assign unique id to `id=uniqueid` attribute on radio button selection

Answer (score 1):

It's adding the same value, because it's the same value, you are using only one variable, assigning once on the controller and then using the same variable three times.

Anyway why do you need to assign a unique id, to each input.

You could solve it, decalring a function on your controller that returns the unique id, and invoking it from your view.

Comment: like this: `<input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-model="startDate.id" id={{uniqueId()}}  />`??

Comment: yes but you will need to define a function in your controller $scope.uniqueId = function() { return new Date().getMilliseconds(); }

Comment: I defined the function in controller but how do I print the value of `id` attribute on radio button selection?

Comment: I am sending unique date values to server on radio button selection so I need unique radio buttons

Comment: So why don't you just send the timestamp when posting data to the server and forget about setting the id? It seems you will have a function that will psot data when user selects the radio button, why don't generate it there?

Comment: @Satyadev why do you want to print the id, you can just check by inspecting element on your browser and verify.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your scope like this:

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bdap82cL/)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="radioExample">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      angular.module('radioExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

          $scope.startDate = {
            id: new Date()
          };
          $scope.specialValue = {
            "value": new Date().getMilliseconds()
          };

          $scope.getUId = function() {
           var charSet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
           var charSetSize = charSet.length;
            var id = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
              var randPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSetSize);
              id += charSet[randPos];
            }
            return id;
          }

        }]);

    </script>
    <form ng-controller="ExampleController" name="myForm">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{::getUId()}}" /> Jan
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{::getUId()}}" /> Feb
      </label>

      <br />
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{::getUId()}}" /> Mar
      </label>
      <br />
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

**edit: You may change the `charSet` to suit your domain of acceptable characters in unique id.**

Comment: Great! This is what I'm looking for. But how do I print the Id to console when radio button is selected?

Comment: Please check this plunkr: `https://plnkr.co/edit/feFAS9dNDpht6TraReTg?p=preview` its printing null values..why?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tZn8flFkwcwhp3H2zNTA?p=preview it is showing the target element of click.

Comment: and I coudnt figure out why the `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`. The documentation states that it is due to `$watch` getting called many times in quick succession. but I don't understand why...

Comment: It is showing target element of click but I want to print the value as we are storing unique id into `id` attribute

Comment: then just use `console.log("#" + $(event.target.id).value)` in jQuery or           `console.log(document.getElementById(event.target.id).value)` in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

**html:**

```
<input type="radio" name="rdboption" ng-value="specialValue" ng-model="startDate.id" id="{{uniqueId()}}" />
```

**js:**

```
angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.startDate = {
        id: new Date()
      };
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "value": new Date().getMilliseconds()
      };

      $scope.uniqueId = function() {
        return new Date().getMilliseconds();
      };

    }]);
```

Comment: I want to assign unique id (or timestamp)  to `id="the_id_you_want"` on click

Comment: removed the off topic answer.

Comment: How do I print value of `id="{{uniqueId()}}"` when radio button is selected?